# How Does 0x Protocol Manage Market Impact for Large Limit Orders?

Tags: 0x

I'm exploring the 0x protocol for decentralized trading and I have a question regarding its handling of large limit orders. I understand that limit orders do not experience slippage by design, as they execute at a specified price. However, when it comes to large orders that could potentially move the market, how does the 0x protocol manage the execution to minimize impact on market price?

Is there an inherent feature in the protocol that spreads the execution of a large order over time to avoid significant price fluctuations, or is it left to the trader to implement a custom solution to this problem? If the protocol does support this, how is it structured? Are there any specific functions or parameters within the 0x smart contracts that address this issue?

Any insights or pointers to relevant sections of the documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help.